create custom toast in smali with apk editor studio
I decompiled the apk with apk editor studio 1.7.1. There is a run method inside a nested class (aptxalsNotify$1).
This run method displays a text only toast message when an aptx enabled bluetooth headset is connected namely aptX or aptX HD. Now I want to modify it show image of the codec instead of the text. I want it to display aptx or aptX HD when either device is connected accordingly. I prepared a custom_toast layout with resource ID "0x7f0b0037. I also prepared all resources IDs for drawables and imageviews. The imageview inside custom_toast layout is called codec_image with resource id "0x7f0800bc", I want the custom toast to display "qti_aptx.png" when aptx device is connected. And "qti_aptx_hd.png" when aptx HD device is connected accordingly. The resource IDs for "qti_aptx.png" is "0x7f070077" and "qti_aptx_hd.png" is "0x7f070078"
I know java but I don't know anything about smali
here is what I need to implement in the smali
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
                ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.codec_image);
                if (codec == aptxalsUIDefs.SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_APTX){
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.qti_aptx);
                } else if (codec == aptxalsUIDefs.SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_APTX_HD) {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.qti_aptx_hd);
                }
                Toast toast = new Toast(context);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 50);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();

<!-- custom_toast_layout.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="8dp">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/codec_image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@null" />

</LinearLayout>


here is the run method from smali
.method public run()V
    .locals 3

    .line 133
    iget v0, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    sget v1, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsUIDefs;->SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_APTX:I

    if-eq v0, v1, :cond_0

    iget v0, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    sget v1, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsUIDefs;->SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_APTX_HD:I

    if-eq v0, v1, :cond_0

    iget v0, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    sget v1, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsUIDefs;->SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_APTX_ADAPTIVE:I

    if-eq v0, v1, :cond_0

    iget v0, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    sget v1, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsUIDefs;->SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_APTX_TWSP:I

    if-ne v0, v1, :cond_2

    .line 137
    :cond_0
    invoke-static {}, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;->access$000()Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v0

    if-eqz v0, :cond_1

    .line 138
    invoke-static {}, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;->access$000()Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->cancel()V

    .line 142
    :cond_1
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->this$0:Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$context:Landroid/content/Context;

    iget v2, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    invoke-static {v0, v1, v2}, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;->access$100(Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;Landroid/content/Context;I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 143
    .local v0, "text":Ljava/lang/String;
    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/String;->isEmpty()Z

    move-result v1

    if-nez v1, :cond_2

    .line 144
    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$context:Landroid/content/Context;

    const/4 v2, 0x0

    invoke-static {v1, v0, v2}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->makeText(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-static {v1}, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;->access$002(Landroid/widget/Toast;)Landroid/widget/Toast;

    .line 145
    invoke-static {}, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;->access$000()Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V

    .line 148
    .end local v0    # "text":Ljava/lang/String;
    :cond_2
    return-void
.end method


I tried using chatGPT to help me with smali and it implemented the code and compiled without error but the toast does not appear.
here is the modified run method from chatGPT
.method public run()V
    .locals 9

    .line 133
    iget v0, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    sget v1, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsUIDefs;->SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_APTX:I

    if-ne v0, v1, :cond_0

    iget v0, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    sget v1, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsUIDefs;->SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_APTX_HD:I

    if-ne v0, v1, :cond_0

    iget v0, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    sget v1, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsUIDefs;->SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_APTX_ADAPTIVE:I

    if-ne v0, v1, :cond_0

    iget v0, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    sget v1, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsUIDefs;->SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_APTX_TWSP:I

    if-eq v0, v1, :cond_1

    :cond_0
    return-void

    :cond_1
    .line 137
    invoke-static {}, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;->access$000()Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v0

    if-eqz v0, :cond_2

    .line 138
    invoke-static {}, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;->access$000()Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->cancel()V

        .line 141
    :cond_2
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$context:Landroid/content/Context;
    invoke-static {v0}, Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;->from(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;
    move-result-object v0

    const v1, 0x7f0800bc
    const/4 v2, 0x0
    invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v2}, Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;->inflate(ILandroid/view/ViewGroup;)Landroid/view/View;
    move-result-object v0
    move-object v1, v0


    .line 142
    const v1, 0x7f0800bc 

    invoke-virtual {v3, v1}, Landroid/view/View;->findViewById(I)Landroid/view/View;

    move-result-object v4

    check-cast v4, Landroid/widget/ImageView;

    iget v5, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    const v6, 0x7f070077

    if-ne v5, v6, :cond_3

    const v5, 0x7f070077

    invoke-virtual {v4, v5}, Landroid/widget/ImageView;->setImageResource(I)V

    :cond_3
    iget v5, p0, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify$1;->val$codec:I

    const v6, 0x7f070078

    if-ne v5, v6, :cond_4

    const v5, 0x7f070078

    invoke-virtual {v4, v5}, Landroid/widget/ImageView;->setImageResource(I)V

    :cond_4
    .line 145
    invoke-static {p0}, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;->access$000()Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v5

    invoke-virtual {v5, v3}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->setView(Landroid/view/View;)V

    .line 146
    invoke-static {p0}, Lcom/qualcomm/qtil/aptxals/aptxalsNotify;->access$000()Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v3

    const v5, 0x8001  # Duration set to Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

    invoke-virtual {v3, v5}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->setDuration(I)V       

    invoke-virtual {v3}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V

    .line 149
    return-void
.end method



What I'd try is to make a tiny app that contains the java code you need, compile it, decompile it, take the smali part from there.

@zapl thanks for the hint I will try this now, it will need some minor adjustments afterwards.

@zapl I managed to create new application , transferred the code , and modified according to my app, here is the new run method https://pastebin.com/bX0ig0Te but I get this error [157,0] There is already a label with that name.
